# Python multiple list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
def test():
    return 1,2

a, b = [test() for _ in range(5)]
```

How do I get `a=[1,1,1,1,1]` and `b=[2,2,2,2,2]` using list comprehension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is the key to this like:

#### Code:

```
a, b = [list(x) for x in zip(*[test() for _ in range(5)])]
```

#### Test Code:

```
def test():
    return 1, 2

a, b = [list(x) for x in zip(*[test() for _ in range(5)])]
print(a, b)
```

#### Results:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Wow this looks really hard to read. Is this used often in software development?

Comment: Yep, this is the way in Python.  Takes some getting used to.  You can always code it more verbosely, but better to learn.

Comment: Also this sounds like a good interview question because it requires understanding of both zip() and list comprehension